Matching for 2 columns but matching all alternatives recuringly in SQL
My data look like this



Col_X
Col_Y




a
b


b
c


c
d


d
e


f
g


t
y


y
r


q
w


n
m


m
k


m
z



My final goal cluster table should be exactly like this:



Cluster




abcde


fg


nmkz


qw


tyr



My pseudo data
select 'a' as x, 'b' as y union all
select 'b' as x, 'c' as y union all
select 'c' as x, 'd' as y union all
select 'd' as x, 'e' as y union all
select 'f' as x, 'g' as y union all
select 't' as x, 'y' as y union all
select 'y' as x, 'r' as y union all
select 'q' as x, 'w' as y union all
select 'n' as x, 'm' as y union all
select 'm' as x, 'k' as y union all
select 'm' as x, 'z' as y 


Please explain your actual requirement, don't make us guess.

... and what have you tried so far?

Recursive with a small preparation to collect all brothers, note that without ordering column this part may be random from one execution to the other one:
with data(x, y) as (
    select 'a' as x, 'b' as y union all
    select 'b' as x, 'c' as y union all
    select 'c' as x, 'd' as y union all
    select 'd' as x, 'e' as y union all
    select 'f' as x, 'g' as y union all
    select 't' as x, 'y' as y union all
    select 'y' as x, 'r' as y union all
    select 'q' as x, 'w' as y union all
    select 'n' as x, 'm' as y union all
    select 'm' as x, 'k' as y union all
    select 'm' as x, 'z' as y 
),
adata(x, y) as (
    select x, listagg(y, '') as y from data d group by x
)
,cte(l, x,y,c,r) as (
    select 1, x, y, x, x
    from adata d
    where not exists(select 1 from adata d1 where d1.y = d.x)

    union all
    
    select c.l + 1, d.x, d.y, c.c || d.x, c.r
    from cte c
    join adata d on d.x = c.y 
)
select c from (
    select r, c || y as c, row_number() over(partition by r order by length(c || y) desc) as rn
    from cte 
)
where rn = 1
;

abcde
nmkz
qw
fg
tyr


hi thanks a lot but you use cte before you assign
